# android parse versions above 1.9.4 not working

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

i have used parse `v1.9.4` for a while and it was working correctly and today i updated to latest version `1.10.2` and i don't recieve any pushes , also tested all `1.10.x` version and no of them work.
what's the problem? should i change any code that i used in `1.9.4` ? i followed docs but it is not working .
also parse `crash report` is not working in `NO VERSION`.

**another question** : how can i edit installationId field to match device id ? i use below code :

```
ParseInstallation installation =   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

    installation.put("installationId", DEVICE_ID);

    installation.saveInBackground();
```

but it throws exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot modify `installationId` property of an _Installation object.
```

please help , thank in advanced

Comment: You should never have to modify installationId?

Comment: @cYrixmorten so how can i achieve unique installation per device ?

Comment: @tyczj yes i know,but it gets reseted after reinstallation also i used :  installation.setObjectId(DEVICE_ID)   but after doing so installation ever is not inserted

Comment: The objectId is unique for each installation already. Device ID by the way can not be assumed unique, rooted devices can modify it. I think your attempts to force your own ways may have caused you the problems you ate facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved my problem, i was using parse on emulator which didn't have `gcm` and parse versions above `v1.9.4` do not work without `gcm` , for using parse in emulator just download `google api system image` .

Comment: were u using genymotion?